# no NSLog after hacking xCode out of provisioning profile and code signing

Tags: iphone, xcode, code-signing, provisioning

I have been following the discussion from [this article](http://www.alexwhittemore.com/?p=270),this is what I have done:

Edit `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Info.plist` to look like this:

```
<key>NATIVE_ARCH</key>
<string>armv6</string>
<key>PLIST_FILE_OUTPUT_FORMAT</key>
<string>binary</string>
<key>PROVISIONING_PROFILE_ALLOWED</key>
<string>NO</string>
<key>PROVISIONING_PROFILE_REQUIRED</key>
<string>NO</string>
<key>SDKROOT</key>
<string>iphoneos2.2</string>
```

Then run this scrip on my computer

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneOS\ Build\ System\ Support.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/
dd if=iPhoneOS\ Build\ System\ Support of=working bs=500 count=255
printf "\xc3\x26\x00\x00" >> working
dd if=iPhoneOS\ Build\ System\ Support of=working bs=1 skip=127504 seek=127504
/bin/mv -n iPhoneOS\ Build\ System\ Support iPhoneOS\ Build\ System\ Support.original
/bin/mv working iPhoneOS\ Build\ System\ Support
chmod a+x iPhoneOS\ Build\ System\ Support
```

It's all that I have done. Now I can run my application on the device without any provisioning or code signing, but the problem is, I don't have any debugging message on the console. On simulator it's OK. Anyone know how I can get them back?
By the way, I am using OSX 10.5.7 and xCode 3.1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a jailbroken device? It sounds to me that you're abusing the SDK, and you're going to find it difficult to get support for this.

Its likely that to be able to debug properly on the device, codesigning is required. Since you've bypassed this, the debugging isn't working.

You may be able to attach the debugger manually?

Comment: I don't know much about this, just that my (jail-broken) device won't work even with code signing and profiling. Thus I look around and find that page, then just follow it.
You mean, no hope for me?

Comment: Probably not. I would recommend you restore your device, update it to iPhone OS 3.1.2 and not jailbreak it.